# Is Bluetooth pairing mode indefinite?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on a BLE device and trying to understand pairing. Say a device has yet to be paired for the first time, can it be set to pairing mode indefinitely? By this I mean, can the device stay in pairing mode as long as it needs to (1 day, 1 week, 1 month, etc.)

Assume the following:
1.Battery power is unlimited
2.The device can only pair to a specified target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the BLE standard doesn't even mention "pairing mode". A device decides in every specific situation when receiving a pairing request or security request how and if it should continue.

It also decides itself when and if it should advertise to make itself connectable, or scan to find other devices to connect to.